# Devise: Issue with routing using devise_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to route my User model sign up form to /sign_in. Tried several things and just used the example given in the devise docs.

I copied in to my routes.rb

```
devise_scope :users do
get "sign_in", to: "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

and rake routes says it should be working and shows what I expected. 
http://s1.postimg.org/do335u8v3/Screen_Shot_2014_06_18_at_11_34_34.png

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
  devise_for :users do
    get '/users/sign_in', :to => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    get '/users/sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get "/users/sign_up", :to => "registrations#new"
  end
```